# SPARQL: Exclude 0.0 from result (Beginner)

Tags: sparql

I would like to exclude all ?Resultat that are 0.0. So I would need some kind of Filter that says `?FakturierterUmsatz != ?SummeVerbuchterAufwand`.

I tried a couple of things (new to SPARQL) but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  ?Projekt
(SUM(distinct?FakturierterUmsatz) as ?SummeFakturierterUmsatz) 
(SUM(distinct ?VerbuchterAufwand) as ?SummeVerbuchterAufwand)
(?FakturierterUmsatz - ?SummeVerbuchterAufwand as ?Resultat)   

WHERE
{

     ?Projekt <http://itopia.ch/iOntology/hasAbrechnung> ?Abrechnung.
?Abrechnung <http://itopia.ch/iOntology/FakturierterUmsatz> ?FakturierterUmsatz.
  ?Abrechnung <http://itopia.ch/iOntology/VerbuchterAufwand>    ?VerbuchterAufwand .
?Abrechnung <http://itopia.ch/iOntology/hasKunde> ?Kunde.
 }    
    GROUP BY ?Projekt ?FakturierterUmsatz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I tried it with the following solution and it seems to work:

```
HAVING (?FakturierterUmsatz - ?SummeVerbuchterAufwand != 0)
```

Comment: Actually, since you're already selecting `((?FakturierterUmsatz - ?SummeVerbuchterAufwand as ?Resultat)`, you could do `HAVING (?Reultat != 0)` which captures the meaning a bit more clearly.